# Multi Threading in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing an Android App, which displays some images from an website in MainActivity. There are some other activities which are basically dealing with the offline contents like dealing with database and configuration.

Currently the App is designed in such a way like, when it navigates from MainActivity to any other activities, first it will destroy itself (calling finish()) and then navigate. Likewise if navigated to MainActivity from some other Activity, those activities will be destroyed before moving.

App works fine, initially. But if the user navigates between activities too frequently, then the image downloading task in the Main Page takes very long time.

```
For Example, if user navigates like
MainActivity --> Activity1 --> MainActivity
```

In the above case, there is no issue displaying the images in MainActivity initially. But in the next instance, it takes unusual time.

What I am planning to to implement a multi threading scenario, which will create a new thread every time the application trie to navigate to MainActivity and destroy the existing one.

```
Thread-0 : MainActivity --> Activity1 (to go Main) --> Kill Thread-0 and Create Thread-1
Thread-1 : MainActivity --> Activity1 --> Activity2 (to go to Main) --> Kill Thread-1 and create Thread-2
```

But I have no clue, how to implement the same. Any suggestion or reference link are most welcomed.

Comment: In general with Android, you create a new `Thread` when you have a job you need to do. Downloading an Image for example. That `Thread` will post back to the UI Thread to give it the information to update, say, an `ImageView`. Why are you making new Threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an AsyncTask like this:

```
   public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private volatile boolean running = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            while (running) {
                // download
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**Activity:**

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     task = new MyTask();
     task.execute();
    }

   @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     if (task != null) task.cancel(true);
    }
```

But for me the easiest way to download and display images is using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Its that simple:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to implement this kind of behavior is with using the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can start it like this

```
new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

Cancel it like this:

```
mTask.cancel(true);
```

And you can use it's `doInBackground()`, `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()` to make it perform like you wish (every method is pretty much self explanatory by the name itself).

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the cache memory logic when loading images.So that if an image is downloaded it would not go for the download again instead it(one activity or the other) will look in the cache.

Comment: The contents in the images are changing every second. So I need the latest images always. So using the cache might not resolve the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

- Create `BaseActivity` class which extends `Activity/AppCompatActivity`.
- extend `BaseActivity` class from your `MainActivity`.
- Do all download tasks in `BaseActivity` using `AsyncTask`

should do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading images frequently creating/destroying a `Thread` would not be a good approach considering the overhead of creating and destroying. `AsyncTask` is an OK approach but risky for memory leaks. My suggestion would be to handle image loading tasks in a service like an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or create a regular [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) with a background thread.